# AngularJS/DataTables - Load data from JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, angularjs

I am using AngularJS and DataTables. I am trying to load data from a JSON file into the table through my JS file. When I tried to load it using ajax, I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` and my table just says "Loading..." until I try to sort it and then it says "No data available in table." Is there a way to get my data to load?

This is what I'm using to draw the table and call the data:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable( {
    "sDom": 'lrtip',
    "aaSorting": [],
    "sAjaxSource": '../controllers/apps.json',
    "sAjaxDataProp": "",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aoColumns": [
                {"apps": "appName"},
                {"apps": "dateCreated"},
                {"apps": "dateUpdated"},
                {"apps": "payload"},
                {"apps": "status"},
                {"apps": "errorCode"},
                {"apps": "errorDesc"}
    ],

});
```

Part of my JSON data:

```
{
"head" : [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Application Name", "class": "filtersearch"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Date Created"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Date Updated"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "Payload"},
    {"id": 5, "name": "Status", "class": "filtersearch"},
    {"id": 6, "name": "Error Code", "class": "filtersearch"},
    {"id": 7, "name": "Error Description"}
    ],

"details" : [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Application Name"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Error Description"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Record Count"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "Record Fail"}
    ],

"status" : [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Active"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Inactive"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Unknown"}
    ],

"errorCode" : [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Code01"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Code02"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Code03"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "Code04"}
    ],

"apps" : [
    {"appName": "App01",
        "dateCreated": "01/01/2015",
        "dateUpdated": "01/04/2015",
        "payload": "Payload01",
        "status": 0,
        "errorCode": 0,
        "errorDesc": "Desc01",
        "recordCount": 1,
        "recordFail": 1},
```

EDIT: I changed my code for `var oTable` - the error is gone but now it is not loading any data.

Comment: Could be worth looking into [this](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/dataReloadWithAjax)

Comment: @Jack I'm using [DataTables.net](http://datatables.net/) and I think it's pretty similar to that

Comment: Just thought it would be worth mentioning since you're using AngularJS :) Do you know what line of the code you posted the error is on?

Comment: Is your JSON well defined? (in the example, it's not)  And are you verifying that the data you expect are actually returned from your call?  I.e., you've used your console tools to check the response, etc?

Comment: @Jack the error is in a jquery.dataTables.js file but I haven't changed anything in that file - I think there's just a problem with the way the data is loading (or not loading).

Comment: @Marc that's just a snippet, but I verified the syntax on a JSON verifier site. Do I use console.log() to check the response?

Comment: in firefox web developer tools, you can view the network tab, and it will show you the requests and responses.  I'd inspect those to make sure you're getting back the data you think you're getting.  Chrome and IE have similar tools

Comment: are you sure you're using Angular? :)

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck, yes, I just didn't include my angular code. I have a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5r5rxkz/4/), but the data is hard-coded instead of in a separate json file (I don't know how to add JSON files to fiddles).

Comment: @Marc the response shows that it's getting the data that's in my JSON file, I just don't think it's plugging the data in right.

Comment: As Valentin said it look more likne jQuery, if you need jQuery functionality You should first consider using jQLite which angularJS is embedded with initially. And As i suppose You get this error undefined because you have defined variable or scope but You haven't assigned any value to it or the value is not reachable in the moment of table creation. I Think using a $watch in AngularJS Could solvle the problem, track the data.

Comment: I changed my code based on a DataTables forum question. The error is gone but now it's not loading any data.